# How to Relay SSL(HTTPS) response through Proxy?

Tags: c#, https, proxy, tcplistener

I have to trace the HTTP traffic .It work without Https. I try for the https, it successfully get the response via Sslstream through the certificate. When i forward ssl response for the relay but it doesn’t getting the response.

Please let me how to relay SSL response?

Please check the following code for the same.

Thanks

```
 public void ThreadHandleHTTPClient(object o)
 {
try{
                Socket client = (Socket)o;

                Stream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
                //Stream outStrem = ns;
                //RECEIVE CLIENT DATA
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int rec = 0, sent = 0, transferred = 0, rport = 0;
                string data = "";
                do
                {
                    rec = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec);
                } while (rec == buffer.Length);

                //PARSE DESTINATION AND SEND REQUEST
                string line = data.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                string e=line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
                Uri uri = new Uri(e);
                if (uri.Scheme == "https" || line.Contains("CONNECT"))
                {
                    rport = 443;
                    //Make tunnel for the HTTPS which is authentic host.
                   SslStream sslStream = sslTunnel(ns, uri.OriginalString, "1.0");
                   ns = sslStream;

                   string remoteUri = "https://" + uri.Scheme;
                   StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(sslStream);


                   string httpCmd = clientStreamReader.ReadLine();
                   string[] splitBuffer = httpCmd.Split(_spaceSplit, 3);
                   remoteUri = remoteUri + splitBuffer[1];

                   myQuery = string.Empty;
                   //Read the SSL Stream save command in myQuery variable.
                   readRequestHeadersEx(clientStreamReader);
                   data = myQuery;
                   data = splitBuffer[0]+" ";
                   data += remoteUri;
                   data += " ";
                   data += splitBuffer[2];
                   data += "\r\n";
                   data += myQuery;
                   data += "\r\n";

                   line = data.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                   uri = new Uri(line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);               

                }
                else
                {
                    rport = 80;                   
                }

                IPHostEntry rh = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.Host);
                Socket remoteserver = new Socket(rh.AddressList[0].AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                remoteserver.Connect(new IPEndPoint(rh.AddressList[0], rport));
                byte[] databytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                remoteserver.Send(databytes, databytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                //START RELAY
                buffer = new byte[2048];
                rec = 0;
                data = "";
                do
                {

                    transferred = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        rec = remoteserver.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        sent = client.Send(buffer, rec, SocketFlags.None);
                        transferred += rec;
                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec);
                    } while (rec == buffer.Length);

                    if (transferred == 0)
                        break;

                } while (transferred > 0);

                client.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

public void Start(IPAddress ip, int port)
            {     
 TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
                listener.Start(100);
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    Thread th = new Thread(ThreadHandleHTTPClient);
                    th.Start(client);
                }

                listener.Stop();         
            }
```

Comment: relay SSL? I am not sure why you are doing this...but SSL is designed to protect against man in middle attacks, which this looks suspiciously like. If indeed this is the case you would need to do something akin to how fiddler does it, using a trusted SSL cert and dynamically create SSL certs for each host you attach to.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, actually i want to record the https and HTTP traffic. Yes it is "Man in Middle" and doing the same thing what you suggest .Apply SSL certs for each host and it's working fine. When I forward the SSLStream response to relay, I am not getting the response.
Please check the below step for the SSL relay,
1)IF CONNECT and https Method found
2)SSL Authenticate
3)Read the SSL stream
4)IF Complete
In short, After the Step-4 , the socket not able able to receive single byte. You may find the   “START RELAY” tag in attached code.

Comment: relay?:which is connects to remote host and receives data and forwarded it ,to local proxy.